# how to access lists (arrays) which have strings, int, and images in container

Tags: flutter, dart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUydp.png)i am new to flutter and programming at all.
i was trying get the data from my list into the container and its giving me ERROR.

this the "home" class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart_things.dart';
import 'item_input.dart';

class ItemCards extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ItemCardsState createState() => _ItemCardsState();
}

class _ItemCardsState extends State<ItemCards> {
  List<PDS> items = [
    PDS(
      itemName: 'Corolla',
      itemPrice: 4000,
      sellerAdd: 'Kabul Afghanitan',
      sellerNumber: 093864774664,
      itemPics: Image.asset(
        '/assets/car.jpg',
        // height: 200.0,
        // width: 200.0,
        // //scale: 1,
      ),
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: items.map((items) {
              Container(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('${items.itemName}'),
                    Image.asset('${items.itemPics}'),
                    Text('${items.itemPrice}'),
                    Text('${items.sellerNumber}'),
                    Text('${items.sellerAdd}'),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            }).toList()),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this the main class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:thisOne/Item_input.dart';
import 'package:thisOne/item_card.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: AfghanBazar(),
    routes: {
      '/itemInput': (context) => ItemInput(),
    },
    theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.red,
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
          //color: Colors.deepOrange,
          elevation: 0,
        )),
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  ));
}

class AfghanBazar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AfghanBazarState createState() => _AfghanBazarState();
}

class _AfghanBazarState extends State<AfghanBazar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        //backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
        title: Text('AFGHAN BAZAR'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: ItemCards(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/itemInput');
        },
        child: Text('+',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 40,
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

i am trying to get those variables(itemName, itemPrice, itemPics, and other list items) in a container, so when i run the code it gives error that column children cannot be null when its not null,
can you please help me get this?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to quote the full error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a problem with your `Image.asset('${items.itemPics}'),` because you're using an Image.asset constructor but the `${items.itemPics}` is already an Image.asset widget.

So you should probably swap:

```
Text('${items.itemName}'),
Image.asset('${items.itemPics}'),
Text('${items.itemPrice}'),
```

to

```
Text('${items.itemName}'),
items.itemPics,
Text('${items.itemPrice}'),
```

Comment: it still gives this error "Column's children must not contain any null values, but a null value was found at index 0"

Comment: You need to `return Container`  in `items.map((items) {` . Modify it to be `items.map((items) { return Container(` . @MtKhalifa